# Best Practice Php Sessions with Angular2

Tags: php, session, angular

I have an angular 2 application using php, when logging in i create a session and this seems to work correctly on api calls. My question is just whether there is a potential when the site is moved to production for sessions to get overidden from different api calls within the angular2 application.

Basically, should a developer avoid sessions when using an Angular2 / REST frontend that only interacts with Php for api calls?

Comment: Best practice? Opinion based and does not belong here on [so]

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to build a large scale "personal learning" shopping cart with MEAN stack with Angular 2. I am using using MongoStore Session to add items to the cart when the user is not logged-in and not Arrays. When the user log-in, the cart session gets cleared and added to the user's item using Mongo DB to store user's info, items, and ordered items. I use Passport, JWT and Bcyrpt for authentication. I use Local Storage to store the token and user id. Hope this helps in building a realistic app.